# Methods of styling GUI components in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm creating a user interface for a java standalone desktop application but the forms, text fields and tables I built using javax.swing and java.awt packages look quite dull. Are there any methods by which these components can be stylized so that they look more appealing (like those beautiful websites made with css and javascript) ?

Comment: Because you mentioned CSS, I feel obligated to mention JavaFX. JavaFX allows you to style components using CSS. If you're looking for some pre-made LAFs, check out substance and trident.

Comment: Instead of styling anything, consider just setting the system LAF so your application looks like an application *should* look for that platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background, border, foreground, etc of these components. Consult [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for useful functions.

Or you can change the look and feel of your entire program. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use Look and Feel, there are libraries that set your all your components with a defined style.

See this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html